# 2 ошибки в коде в коде Assets (43,66): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected и ещё Assets (45,66): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class Geme : MonoBehaviour {

    private Cubepos nowCube = new Cubepos(0, 1, 0);
    public float cubeChangePlaceSpeed = 0.5f;
    public transform cubeToPlace;

    private List<Vector3> allCubesPositions = new List<Vector3> {
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (-1, 0, 0),
        new Vector3 (0, 1, 0),
        new Vector3 (0, 0, 1),
        new Vector3 (0, 0, -1),
        new Vector3 (1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3 (-1, 0, -1),
        new Vector3 (-1, 0, 1),
        new Vector3 (1, 0, -1),
    };

    private void Start() {    
        StartCoroutine(ShowCubePlace());
    }
     
    IEnumerator ShowCubePlace() {    
        while(true) { 
            SpawnPositions();

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(cubeChangePlaceSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPositions() { 
        List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x + 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x - 1, nowCube.y, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, +1 nowCube.z)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y + 1, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, -1 nowCube.z)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y - 1, nowCube.z));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z + 1));
        if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.x - 1)))
            positions.Add(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, nowCube.z - 1));

        cubeToPlace.position = positions[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, positions.Count)];
    }

    private bool IsPositionEmpty(Vector3 targetPos) {
        if (targetPos.y == 0)
            return false;

        foreach (Vector3 pos in AllCubesPositions) {
            if (pos.x == targetPos.x && pos.y == targetPos.y && pos.z == targetPos.z)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}

struct Cubepos{
    public int x, y, z;

    public Cubepos(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public Vector3 getVector() {
        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    public void setVector(Vector3 pos) {
        x = Convert.ToIns32(pos.x);
        y = Convert.ToIns32(pos.y);
        z = Convert.ToIns32(pos.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам же пишут где ошибка. Почему нельзя разобрать эти строки детально, просмотреть?

вот например

```
if (IsPositionEmpty(new Vector3(nowCube.x, nowCube.y, -1 nowCube.z)))
                                                     ^^^^^^ что это?
```

аналогично в дргих местах. посмотрите на строку, посомтрите в документацию что как пишется (например как пишется vector3, как пишется метод с параметрами, как пишется `if`), проанализируйте свой код - совпадает с документациейц? Нет? Тогда исправьте на корреткные